# Grep Word Count is Empty

Tags: linux, grep, mingw

```
grep -a 'END:' RTFC-1.bin | wc -l
```

This command is not giving me the word count 'END:' happens to be in a Binary file. I am testing this command on MINGW32 on Windows.

Comment: What is your goal, in counting "lines" in a binary file?  Binary files do not necessarily have lines, per se.  So what are you **really** trying to get from the `wc -l`?

Comment: Do you want `grep -a -c 'END:' RTFC-1.bin` to get the count, or are you just trying to see if it exists at all, when `if grep -a -q 'END:' RTFC-1.bin; then echo found; fi` might be the answer.